# Creating Database in WordPress

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I am creating a WordPress plugin and among other things this plugin is supposed to create a new database table. On account of having little experience with SQL, I can't seem to create the table. 
Here is my code:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'ol_plugin_create_db' );

function ol_plugin_create_db() {
      global $wpdb;
      $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
      $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'olplugin';
      $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
           Name varchar(255),
       Email varchar(255)
       ) $charset_collate;";
       require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
       dbDelta( $sql );
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: it says There is no database called "(prefix)_olplugin"

Comment: just echo $wpdb->prefix; and check what prefix is set or echo $table_name; die();

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of you are using capital letters as field name or there may be some syntax problem.

**considering : -You are creating a table here not a database**

> You must put each field on its own line in your SQL statement.
>
> You must have two spaces between the words PRIMARY KEY and the
>   definition of your primary key.
>
> You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you
>   must include at least one KEY.
>
> You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.
>
> Field types must be all lowercase.
>
> SQL keywords, like CREATE TABLE and UPDATE, must be uppercase.
>
> You must specify the length of all fields that accept a length
>   parameter. int(11), for example.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'ol_plugin_create_db' );
function ol_plugin_create_db() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $jal_db_version;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'olplugin';

    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name varchar(255),
        email varchar(255),
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta( $sql );
}
```

Reference :- [Creating Tables With Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins)